# How to generate raw binary (*.bin) with CMake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Is there any simple and canonical way within CMake to compile C and/or C++ code into a raw binary (`*.bin`)?

What I would *like* is something equivalent to:

```
# Imaginary syntax
add_binary(something ${source_files})
```

to produce a `something.bin` while still having "`something`" act as a proper CMake target. Ideally I want this to still interoperate with the normal built-in mechanisms like `target_include_directories`/`target_compile_options`, and other C and C++-specific properties.

Effectively, I want CMake to produce something equivalent to;

```sh
i686-elf-gcc -T <linker script(s)...> -o <raw_binary>.bin -ffreestanding -nostdlib <object(s)...> -lgcc
```

I can probably achieve something *similar* by leveraging `OBJECT` libraries in a function with a custom target that executes `${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}` against `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:${target}>`:

```
# Untested
function(add_binary target)
  add_library("${target}.objects" OBJECT ${ARGN})

  set(output_name "{target}.bin")
  set(linker_flags
    "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:${target}.objects,LINK_OPTIONS>"
  )
  set(link_libraries
    "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:${target}.objects,LINK_LIBRARIES>"
  )

  add_custom_target("${target}"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_LINKER}" "${linker_flags}" -o "${output_name}" $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${target}.objects> -lgcc "${linker_libraries}"
    DEPENDS "${target}.objects"
    BYPRODUCT "${output_name}"
  )
endfunction()
```

However custom targets aren't able to reuse the standard built-in mechanisms that I would otherwise like to use. This will force me to define such properties on the object library "${target}.object" instead of the canonical target "`${target}`" (which may work, but is not desired if it's possible to avoid).

**To emphasize:**

- `add_library(... SHARED ...)` does not work because this produces a shared library with `-fPIC`
- `add_library(... STATIC ...)` does not work because it produces an archive of objects (need raw binary image, not an archive)
- `add_executable(...)` does not work because it expects the symbol `main` to be defined. This also seems to implicitly pass `-lstdc++` which is not available in my environment.
- `add_library(... OBJECT ...)` *may* work as an intermediate step (?)

At this point I'm mostly out of ideas, and feel as though I may be stuck with the hack approach. Any suggestions are welcome. I'd love to know how this is normally handled, because i feel like there must be a simpler way.

---

<sup>Tagging this [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [c](/questions/tagged/c) as well for visibility, since this applies to both languages.</sup>